# Xmonad set layout based on enviornment variable

Tags: haskell, xmonad

Suppose I have an env variable `IS_REMOTE`. I would like to have a set of layouts if it is "1", and another set if it is not, or undefined. So far I have

```
import XMonad
import XMonad.Config.Desktop
import XMonad.Hooks.ManageDocks
import XMonad.Layout.LayoutModifier
import XMonad.Layout.MultiColumns
import XMonad.Layout.PerWorkspace
import XMonad.Layout.ThreeColumns
import Data.Maybe
import System.Environment

main = do
  isRemoteEnv <- lookupEnv "IS_REMOTE"
  xmonad $ desktopConfig
    {
      layoutHook = myLayout (fromMaybe "0" isRemoteEnv)
    }

myLayout remote = if remote == "1"
  then onWorkspace "web" (avoidStruts $ (multiCol [1] 1 0.02 (-0.5)) ||| Full) $
       (avoidStruts $ (ThreeColMid 1 0.02 (1/2)) ||| Full)
  else onWorkspace "web" (avoidStruts $ Mirror (multiCol [1] 1 0.02 (-0.5)) ||| Full) $
       (avoidStruts $ Mirror (ThreeColMid 1 0.02 (1/2)) ||| Full)
```

This does not compile, because (I think) the two branches of `if` have different types. But this is at the limit of my Haskell knowledge. What is the correct way to do this?

```
xmonad.hs:21:8: error:
    * Couldn't match type `Mirror MultiCol' with `MultiCol'
      Expected type: PerWorkspace
                       (ModifiedLayout AvoidStruts (Choose MultiCol Full))
                       (ModifiedLayout AvoidStruts (Choose ThreeCol Full))
                       a
        Actual type: PerWorkspace
                       (ModifiedLayout AvoidStruts (Choose (Mirror MultiCol) Full))
                       (ModifiedLayout AvoidStruts (Choose (Mirror ThreeCol) Full))
                       a
    * In the expression:
        onWorkspace
          "web" (avoidStruts $ Mirror (multiCol [1] 1 0.02 (- 0.5)) ||| Full)
          $ (avoidStruts $ Mirror (ThreeColMid 1 0.02 (1 / 2)) ||| Full)
      In the expression:
        if remote == "1" then
            onWorkspace
              "web" (avoidStruts $ (multiCol [1] 1 0.02 (- 0.5)) ||| Full)
              $ (avoidStruts $ (ThreeColMid 1 0.02 (1 / 2)) ||| Full)
        else
            onWorkspace
              "web" (avoidStruts $ Mirror (multiCol [1] 1 0.02 (- 0.5)) ||| Full)
              $ (avoidStruts $ Mirror (ThreeColMid 1 0.02 (1 / 2)) ||| Full)
      In an equation for `myLayout':
          myLayout remote
            = if remote == "1" then
                  onWorkspace
                    "web" (avoidStruts $ (multiCol [1] 1 0.02 (- 0.5)) ||| Full)
                    $ (avoidStruts $ (ThreeColMid 1 0.02 (1 / 2)) ||| Full)
              else
                  onWorkspace
                    "web" (avoidStruts $ Mirror (multiCol [1] 1 0.02 (- 0.5)) ||| Full)
                    $ (avoidStruts $ Mirror (ThreeColMid 1 0.02 (1 / 2)) ||| Full)
   |
21 |   else onWorkspace "web" (avoidStruts $ Mirror (multiCol [1] 1 0.02 (-0.5)) ||| Full) $
   |        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The core problem here comes from Haskell's lack of first-class support for existential or union types. A much simpler example is that `show $ if x then 'a' else "abc"` is invalid, even though `if x then show 'a' else show "abc"` is valid. Anyway, to solve your problem, this isn't very pretty, but it works:

```
import XMonad
import XMonad.Config.Desktop
import XMonad.Hooks.ManageDocks
import XMonad.Layout.LayoutModifier
import XMonad.Layout.MultiColumns
import XMonad.Layout.PerWorkspace
import XMonad.Layout.ThreeColumns
import Data.Kind
import Data.Maybe
import System.Environment

main = do
  isRemoteEnv <- lookupEnv "IS_REMOTE"
  case myLayout (fromMaybe "0" isRemoteEnv) of Layout c -> xmonad $ desktopConfig {
      layoutHook = c
    }

myLayout remote = if remote == "1"
  then Layout $ onWorkspace "web" (avoidStruts $ (multiCol [1] 1 0.02 (-0.5)) ||| Full) $
       (avoidStruts $ (ThreeColMid 1 0.02 (1/2)) ||| Full)
  else Layout $ onWorkspace "web" (avoidStruts $ Mirror (multiCol [1] 1 0.02 (-0.5)) ||| Full) $
       (avoidStruts $ Mirror (ThreeColMid 1 0.02 (1/2)) ||| Full)
```

It uses [the `Layout` existential type](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/xmonad-0.15/docs/XMonad-Core.html#t:Layout) to make both branches be the same type.

Comment: @DanielWagner That appears to not work, unfortunately: ``No instance for (Read (Layout Window)) arising from a use of `xmonad'``

Comment: It works! Thanks for the help! Could you explain why in my original code, the `{` after `desktopConfig` can be in the next line, but cannot in your version?

Comment: @MetroWind Something to do with layout. I'm not really sure of the exact reason, sorry.